# If $A \neq I \in M_{n\times n} (\mathbb R)$ and $A^2 + 3A -4I =0$ then $A = -4I$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that:
$$I \neq A \in M_{n \times n} (\mathbb R) \; , \; A^2 + 3A - 4I = 0$$

I have to prove or disprove that:
$$A = -4I$$

Here's what I did so far:

> Activate vector $v$ on the given equation $\rightarrow A^2v + 3Av - 4Iv = 0v \rightarrow \lambda^2v + 3\lambda v - 4v = 0 \rightarrow \lambda_1 = 1, \lambda_2 = -4$.
>
> $A =_? -4I \rightarrow Av =_? -4Iv \rightarrow \lambda v =_? -4v \rightarrow \lambda =_? -4 \rightarrow$ correct because one of the eigenvalues (if they exist) of $A$ is $-4$

Is what I did correct? Can I assume it has an eigenvalue for each vector $v$ if it is not given? Overall, did I solve it completely, or is there a major flaw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually your computation (sort of) implies that the matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}-4 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

would be interesting to study. Check whether it satisfies your equation. (After you have done that, think carefully about your proposed solution.)

Comment: Oh correct!
Will do!

Comment: I can't think of what I can manipluate with that matrix.. can you give me a direction please?

Comment: @TheNotMe Did you really compute $A^2+3A-4I$?

Comment: That's one of the questions I have asked. Can I do what I did? I merely said that if $A$ has eigenvalues, then I can apply a vector $v$ to my equation, and get what I got.
Is it wrong?

Comment: @TheNotMe: You should do that computation first.

Comment: @TheNotMe Compute $A^2+3A-4I$ *for the matrix I gave you*.

Comment: Wait wait.
$A^2 + 3A - 4I =0 \rightarrow (A+4I)(A-I) = 0$ which means $A=I$ or $A = -4I$, we are given that $A \neq I$ then it is forced to be $A = -4I$. Is that correct?

Comment: @TheNotMe: $AB=0$ does not imply $A=0$ or $B=0$.

Comment: No, you can't. You've shown that $A=-4I$ does not cause a contradiction with the eigenvalues of $A$, but not that it is the only possible solution, which is what you are trying to prove. Compute the matrix mrf has given to see what happens to your proposition.

Comment: Well, it DOES give true to the given equation, since ${\begin{pmatrix} -4 & 0 \\ 0& 1 \end{pmatrix}}^2 + 3 \cdot \begin{pmatrix} -4 & 0 \\ 0& 1 \end{pmatrix} - 4\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0& 1 \end{pmatrix} = 0 $ indeed, but what does that mean?!

Comment: You were trying to show that if $A$ satisfies $A^2+3A-4I=0$, it must be that $A=-4I$, right? So is this statement true or false, based on your calculation?

Comment: What is bothering me, is why can we take $A = \begin{pmatrix} -4 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ ? I mean, what if it had not any eigenvalues from the start? and even if it does, $A$ is $\in M_{n\times n} (\mathbb R)$ so why could we take it as $M_{2 \times 2}$? Of course I understand that $A$ is NOT the matrix you gave me... it is not $n \times n$

Comment: $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ refers to the set of all square matrices with real entries. $n$ is not a fixed integer here; a $2\times 2$ matrix with real entries belongs to both $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ as well as $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$.

Here $A$ is a specific, $2\times 2$ counter-example; I am not sure what you mean by why we can take it.

Comment: Wait. So $\begin{pmatrix} -4 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is not of the form $-4I$. But it satisfies the equation. I guess that means that the statement is false. Because a matrix not of that form satisfies it too. But, is that the correct answer? I feel like I'm missing a few points.

Comment: Yes, the statements is false with the matrix you mentioned as a counter-example. That is the correct answer, for precisely the reason that you have mentioned.

Comment: Thank you all for being so patient with me!
Thanks alotttt!